# SendKeys GUI Bug

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys

I've made this program in C#:

```
namespace Spammer
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int delay, y = 1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delay = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            timer1.Interval = delay;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                String textt = textBox1.Text;
                SendKeys.SendWait(textt);
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine most of the time, and it can really send keys quickly.

But when I insert a delay of, for example, 10 MS, it's very hard to click the "Stop" button to stop it. The only way to stop the sending is to close the program and I don't want to do that.

Is there anyway I can send keys very quickly, like 5-10 MS, without it impairing my ability to press the buttons inside the program? I can't click while it's sending quickly...

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using [`SendWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That will wait for the target application to respond - and while that's happening, *your* application won't be able to respond to user input. If you use [`Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `SendWait`, your UI thread won't be blocked waiting for the key press to be processed.

Comment: Thank you, but sadly it doesn't work.

I've changed it from SendWait to Send, but it still does the same thing.

The buttons in the program cannot be pressed, whenever I click them nothing happens (they only have that blue thing around them).

I just can't click them, and even when I'm clicking them a lot of times, nothing happens. It keeps sending keys even though it's now Send and not SendWait.

What can I do?

Comment: @BarSharabani: What do you mean by "that blue thing"? It's really not clear what's going on, to be honest.

Comment: When you hover the mouse over the buttons, a blue frame around them appears (at least on Win7/Win8). So when I try to click them that blue frame appears and it's impossible to click them. I just can't click them no matter what I do.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce the issue.  The app is sending a keystroke every 10 milliseconds.  To me, this is not at all surprising that the app is causing freezes.  A keystroke every 10 milliseconds is quite a barrage to the active App.  Threading is not going to help.  Why is this behavior surprising?

In other words, I don't expect things to work out well when I overload the message pump.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Spammer//your own namesapce
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int delayInMilliseconds, y = 1;
        private Timer timer1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //StartTimerWithThreading();       
            SetupTimer();
        }

        void StartTimerWithThreading()
        {
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    SetupTimer();
                });
        }

        void SetupTimer()
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();//Assume system.windows.forms.timer
            textBox2.Text = "10";//new delay
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;//handler
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            delayInMilliseconds = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            timer1.Interval = delayInMilliseconds;
            timer1.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String textt = textBox1.Text;
            SendKeys.SendWait(textt);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed the SendWait to Send, but it still doesn't work.

So what should I do? Just create a separate thread?

Comment: Task.Factory.StartNew is an easy way to do it.  If u prefer I can write something more specific in a few minutes

Comment: Yes Brian, if you could do that, please, it'd be very nice.

I've now tried to run the SendKeys on a separate thread with no success. I mean, I've made the thread and all, but using the timer from the UI to work with the second thread is problematic and I failed doing it.

Comment: Thanks, there's just one small issue: "Error 1 'Spammer.Form1.Dispose(bool)': no suitable method found to override"

Comment: @BarSharabani - If you copied the code above be sure to change the namespace back to your own.  Otherwise the designer generated code will break.

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is instead of adding code to a `Click` event handler for your button, we need a `MouseDown` event handler:

```
//MouseDown event handler for the button2
private void button2_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   timer1.Enabled = false;
}
```

Or you can keep using the `Click` event handler but we send the key only when the `MouseButtons` is not `Left` like this:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   String textt = textBox1.Text;
   if(MouseButtons != MouseButtons.Left) SendKeys.Send(textt);
}
//then you can freely click your button to stop it.
```